# Could someone point me to the normal score transform and its use in R?

Tags: r, spss

I'd like to transform a variable (which is not normal at all) using the equivalent command Rank Cases...-->Normal Scores employed by SPSS. I want to do this using R. I've found out that SPSS uses Blom's Formula to carry this out.

Could you help me or give any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Best Regards!

Comment: Never used Blom's formula, but a quick perusal of the IBM SPSS Website doesn't make it look too complicated. It seems you could code this up in about 4 lines of R code and check against the SPSS function pretty easily: http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/spssstat/v20r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.spss.statistics.help%2Fsyn_rank_fraction.htm You may even be able to entice someone to help you with the R code if you provide a reproducible example dataset and the output from the SPSS command.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what Blom's formula is, but the `powerTransform` function in the `car` package might do what you want. The function uses Box-Cox transformations

```
x <- exp(qnorm(runif(100)))
require(car)
powerTransform(x)
#Estimated transformation parameters 
#          x 
#-0.02340301 
xT <- x^(-0.02340301)
```

Plotting the densities of the untransformed and transformed variables shows the effect of the transformation.
[image]

Comment: thanks for your help. However, I've tried your approach with a different x and I'm not getting a normal transformation. Take, for example x=runif(200), and you'll see what I mean. However, I've found the box.cox.powers useful in this sense. I used the following code:

Comment: I don't see your code Nestorghh, but it works for me. If you used `x <- runif(200)`, the variable `x` has a uniform distribution and when you calculate the transformation parameters using `car::powerTransform` the resulting transformation is (more or less) normally distributed.

Comment: I'm sorry. I've realized you're right. It turns out that both functions `box.cox.powers` and `powerTransform` do the same. I've been running different experiments with a code similar to the one you've posted in your answer and I'm getting transformations more or less normally distributed.  <\br> However, surely you've heard about normal scores transformations and I'd like to know when is more appropriate to use this kind of transformations than the Box-Cox approach. could you give me any suggestions? I appreciate your help in advance. Regards!

Comment: Hmm, maybe if you supplied a bit more info about what you're trying to do exactly? An alternative might be `xT <- qqnorm(x, plot.it=FALSE)$x`. Have a look at `?qqnorm` and `?ppoints` which is linked from the documentation of `qqnorm`.

Comment: Great @smillig, that's exactly the other approach I've used. But, my question is: when is more appropiate to use `xT <- qqnorm(x, plot.it=FALSE)$x` than the Box-Cox code you used before? Could you give some examples? In which scenarios you'd use one or the other? Right now, I'm not using this for a specific objective. My boss wanted to translate the spss code to an R one. Thanks for your help!  Regards.

Comment: @Nestorghh - re: your last point, you may want to ask a new question at stats.stackexchange.com as it's more tailored to stats questions than SO.